# Parse.User.current() not consistent when using HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

Not sure if I'm missing something, but Parse.User.current() isn't persisted when switching from HTTP to HTTPS... At least that's an issue on my end!
How to check this:

Sign up to:
http://todolist.parseapp.com (vanilla Parse's TODO App)

Then enter the following URL
https://todolist.parseapp.com on your web browser.

Instead of being presented the Todo UI, you're presented the signup/sign in.

What's wrong?

Comment: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Jan/10/Loosing-a-Cookie-when-switching-from-http-to-https   may want to look that over

Comment: stay with https all the time

Comment: @RobertRowntree yes, I suppose that's what I'll have to do. So, there's no solution?